A simple cross-number puzzle
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

Fill each square in this cross-number with a non-zero digit such that all of the conditions in the clues are fulfilled. The digits used are not necessarily distinct.
1 ACROSS. A composite factor of $1001$
3 ACROSS. Not a palindrome
5 ACROSS. $pq^3$ where $p$, $q$ prime and $p \ne q$
1 DOWN. One more than a prime, one less than a prime
2 DOWN. A multiple of $9$
4 DOWN. $p^3q$ using the same $p$, $q$ as 5 ACROSS


This puzzle comes from the Senior Kangaroo 2019 contest.

Solved grid:

 

Solution:

 First, notice that for prime $p\neq q$, we require both $pq^3$ and $p^3q$ to be 2-digit numbers. This means that $\{p,q\}=\{2,3\}$, since the next largest prime, $5^3=125$ is already 3 digits long. So, 5 ACROSS and 4 DOWN are $24$ or $54$.


 Now, note that the only 2-digit composite factors of $1001$ are $77$ and $91$. The grid now looks like:


 1 DOWN tells us immediately that we are looking for a 2-digit even number in the middle of a pair of twin primes. We know that the even number must start with $7$ or $9$; the only twin primes in this vicinity are $(71,73)$, so 1 DOWN has answer $\boxed{72}$. This also allows us to figure out that 1 ACROSS is $\boxed{77}$. The grid now looks like:


 3 ACROSS is not a palindrome, so 4 DOWN must be $\boxed{54}$, and 5 ACROSS must be $\boxed{24}$. This corresponds to $p=3$ and $q=2$. The grid now looks like:


 The final observation is that 2 DOWN is a multiple of $9$. In particular, its digit sum must be divisible by $9$. This means the middle cell must contain a $0$ or a $9$. However, the puzzle states that all cells must contain nonzero numbers, so the middle cell contains a $9$. After filling this in, we have solved the puzzle!


Besides the answer of @DanDan面 here above, I found some more solutions, because

 (1ACROSS) besides 77 and 91, other valid factors are 11 and 13 (their counterparts). Right? I suppose I'm wrong, but I'm new here.

This yields the following solutions:

 1  1  █
2  6  5
█  2  4


 1  3  █
2  4  5
█  2  4


 1  1  █
8  6  5
█  2  4


 1  1  █
8  3  2
█  5  4


 1  3  █
8  4  5
█  2  4


 1  3  █
8  1  2
█  5  4

EDIT: These solutions are not valid. My error here is that I mistaken "prime factors" for "composite factors"

Welcome to Puzzling, Klaas :) The problem here is that 11 and 13 are prime, not composite, so although they are factors they are not composite factors. Sorry!

@Stiv, ah thanks! I learned something today!

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Also, 122 is not divisible by 9, but I found that 162 is.

Oh, yes indeed.
